# How does the Google Reader menu stay in place?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'd like to replicate the functionality of the Google Reader left navigation (where you find the Subscribe button, 'Home', 'All Items', etc).

I looked at the HTML and CSS but I can't figure it out. They're not using frames, and I didn't find any ***position:fixed*** statements.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: What menu?  The menu that lists your subscriptions?  The down-arrow menu that you can click on a subscription?  The menu along the top edge of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses fixed height (changed on resize) and `overflow-y: auto` on the 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the menu on left with headings 'All Items', 'Explore' and 'Subscriptions'?

If so look in the code for `<div id="sections-holder"` this has an inline height and `overflow:auto` which adds the scroll-bar

So in effect the build of the menu is standard its the window on the right that causes the effect

But let me know if you mean somewhere else...